# How to replace singleton (a data source provider) by Guice?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, guice

Hello I'm currently working on a xtext graphical editor which is somehow like the ui editor in Android. You can create different ui components by dragging and dropping in the graphical view or code it by hand in a text editor. Either the modification will be serialized into the document.

So here comes a question. As I need to provide the only document source to the whole application I used a singleton class. But I have read some articles which suggest avoiding using singletons so I would like to replace the singleton class by dependency injection. It looks like I have to pass the document as the parameter though a lot of classes.

Is there a way to inject the data source provider automatically by Guice? (Since Xtext already integrated with Guice I would also like to use it rather than other Dependency Injection framework.)

[image: Simple UML diagram here]

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide UML diagram of what was before and after you made changes

Comment: @Imran I have added a UML diagram, hope it helps you.

Comment: What about creating a static member variable in the base class? You can inject this dependency via a Setter (Not through Constructor) method exposed in the base class. In that way, it would be easy to unit test the sub classes too.

Answer (score 0):

There is support for [Singleton](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Scopes) scope in Guice itself which does not create a new instance every time.

```
@Singleton
public class DatasourceProvider{
  /* everything here should be threadsafe! */
}
```

So here the Guice takes care that there is only one instance and whenever you will ask to inject `DatasourceProvider` it will return that same instance.

Comment: Well, I think there's no difference with `getInstance()` method. What I really want is to make the specific file to be the injected dependency.

Comment: @dark_chenshifei I did not get what you want to achieve. Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for the same.

Comment: Sorry for my expression, but I have added a UML diagram and modified the description, hope it would help you to  understand.